# arduino switch control - three output

Tags: arduino

I want to play mp3 using Arduino. 
Is it possible to change the speaker channel for each audio file?

1.mp3 is played on A speaker and 2.mp3 is played on B speaker and 3.mp3 is played on C speaker.

I want a way to play sequentially, not simultaneously.

Please refer to the photo.
https://ibb.co/b6zKdH1

I have configured it as 4ch relays. But I do not know how to connect the question mark part.

Please refer to the photo.
https://ibb.co/TgWq7Cr

Comment: multiplex it! what arduino is that?

Comment: PAM8610 is stereo. It can only drive two speakers. As shown in your image you would need some multiplexing mechanism as you are only using a single speaker output.

Comment: I have configured it as 4ch relays. But I do not know how to connect the question mark part.